# How to copy an App Engine Datastore entity

Tags: python, google-app-engine, copy, google-cloud-datastore

How can I copy an entity created from my `Geo` model:

```
class Geo(db.Model):
    title = db.StringProperty()
    link = db.StringProperty()
    updated = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now =True)
    author = db.ReferenceProperty(MyUser)
    id = db.StringProperty()
    entry = db.ListProperty(db.Key)
```

Comment: This question is already answered by this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2687724/copy-an-entity-in-google-app-engine-datastore-in-python-without-knowing-property

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Copy an entity in Google App Engine datastore in Python without knowing property names at 'compile' time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2687724/copy-an-entity-in-google-app-engine-datastore-in-python-without-knowing-property)