# Changing the key name of an entity

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I understand that they are not supposed to be changed, this is somewhat of a schema migration and only a one-time thing.

I would like to change the key names of entities in my Google App Engine application, effectively deleting and re-crating an entity and updating all references to it.

What is the best way to do this? I'm interesting in hearing anyone's experience with such things.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since changing the key name is functionally identical to creating a new, identical entity with that key, what you want to do is clone the entity with the new key. [Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2687724/copy-an-entity-in-google-app-engine-datastore-in-python-without-knowing-property) some code that does just that.