# How to read old property values in a _pre_put_hook

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

I am trying to implement an ndb model audit so that all changes to properties are stored within each model instance. Here is the code of the _pre_put_hook I chose to implement that.

```
def _pre_put_hook(self):
    # save a history record for updates
    if not (self.key is None or self.key.id() is None):
        old_object = self.key.get(use_cache=True)
        for attr in dir(self):
            if not callable(getattr(self, attr)) and not attr.startswith("_"):
                if getattr(self, attr) != getattr(old_object, attr):
                    logging.debug('UPDATE: {0}'.format(attr))
                    logging.debug('OLD: {0} NEW: {1}'.format(getattr(old_object, attr), getattr(self, attr)))
```

The problem is old_object is always populated with the same values of the self (object) being updated. How can I access the property values of the old object BEFORE the put() being actually made (_pre_put)?

Comment: Could you add a little more context? Maybe the complete model? Why get() the entity from inside the hook (again)? I you want to put() a changed entity, I presume you've already fetched it.

Comment: Try self.key.get(use_cache=False), since the context cache will have a reference to the same entity (self).

Comment: Use the `_post_get_hook` to squirrel away the original values, so that you have them available to you when `_pre_put_hook` is run.

Comment: Thanks @DavidBennett: your `self.key.get(use_cache=False)` suggestion worked just right! I get the old values in the object as it is fetched from the datastore before applying the put().

Comment: @Cato How did you end up solving this?

Comment: @Lee I used David Bennett's solution: I worked on this almost a decade ago, so I don't clearly remember all the context. But reading the comments here, it is clear David's solution worked just fine.

Answer (score 6):

**EDIT:**

I realized over time I was doing a bunch of work that didn't need to be done (alot of CPU/memory used copying entire entities and passing them around when may not be needed).  Here's the updated version which stores a reference to the original protobuf and only deserializes it if you need it

```
  __original = None    # a shadow-copy of this object so we can see what changed... lazily inflated
  _original_pb = None  # the original encoded Protobuf representation of this entity

  @property
  def _original(self):
    """
     Singleton to deserialize the protobuf into a new entity that looks like the original from database
    """
    if not self.__original and self._original_pb:
      self.__original = self.__class__._from_pb(self._original_pb)
    return self.__original

  @classmethod
  def _from_pb(cls, pb, set_key=True, ent=None, key=None):
    """
    save copy of original pb so we can track if anything changes between puts
    """
    entity = super(ChangesetMixin, cls)._from_pb(pb, set_key=set_key, ent=ent, key=key)
    if entity._original_pb is None and not entity._projection:
      # _from_pb will get called if we unpickle a new object (like when passing through deferred library)
      #   so if we are being materialized from pb and we don't have a key, then we don't have _original
      entity.__original = None
      entity._original_pb = pb
    return entity
```

---

Make a clone of the entity when you first read it:

[Copy an entity in Google App Engine datastore in Python without knowing property names at 'compile' time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2687724/copy-an-entity-in-google-app-engine-datastore-in-python-without-knowing-property)

and put it on the entity itself so it can be referenced later when desired.  That way you don't have to do a second datastore read just to make the comparison

We override two different Model methods to make this happen:

```
@classmethod
def _post_get_hook(cls, key, future):
    """
    clone this entity so we can track if anything changes between puts

    NOTE: this only gets called after a ndb.Key.get() ... NOT when loaded from a Query
      see _from_pb override below to understand the full picture

    also note: this gets called after EVERY key.get()... regardless if NDB had cached it already
      so that's why we're only doing the clone() if _original is not set...
    """
    entity = future.get_result()
    if entity is not None and entity._original is None:
        entity._original = clone(entity)

@classmethod
def _from_pb(cls, pb, set_key=True, ent=None, key=None):
    """
    clone this entity so we can track if anything changes between puts

    this is one way to know when an object loads from a datastore QUERY
      _post_get_hook only gets called on direct Key.get()
      none of the documented hooks are called after query results

    SEE: https://code.google.com/p/appengine-ndb-experiment/issues/detail?id=211
    """
    entity = super(BaseModel, cls)._from_pb(pb, set_key=set_key, ent=ent, key=key)
    if entity.key and entity._original is None:
        # _from_pb will get called if we unpickle a new object (like when passing through deferred library)
        #   so if we are being materialized from pb and we don't have a key, then we don't have _original
        entity._original = clone(entity)
    return entity
```